# Accessing non-public schema in PostgreSQL with Pentaho

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, pentaho

Let me start by saying, what I know about Pentaho wouldn't fill up a single paragraph.  I'm more knowledgeable about PostgreSQL.  I'm working with some contractors that are building a set of monthly reports in Pentaho (v. 4.5) for my company.  Some of the data needs to go through a ETL process and get rolled up for reporting purposes.  From a dba(ish) point of view, I would like to move these tables into a separate PostgreSQL schema.

I know that Pentaho is often times used with MySQL (which doesn't have schemas) and I'm concerned this might cause problems.  I've done some "googlin'" and I don't turn up a lot of hits on the topic, but I did find a closed [bug from a few years ago](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-3441) - thus implying that the functionality should be supported.

before I do this, I would like to see if anyone knows of a reason this will fail or be a bad idea.  (or if you've done it an it works great, please let me know that, too).

Final notes: I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1.5, and I don't have access to a Pentaho instance to even test this myself.  And I'm hoping the good folks in the Stackoverflow community will share their expertise and save me from having to install one and the hours of playing/testing to get an idea of this is a bad idea.

EDIT:

I sort of knew this question was a bit vague, but I was hoping that some one would read it and share any experience they have.  So, Let me spell it out more clearly and ask more *explicit* questions.

I have not done anything.  I don't know Pentaho.  I don't want to learn Pentaho (not that there is anything wrong with Pentaho...  It's just not where my interests are right now).  My company hired contractors (I did not hire them).  They have experience with Pentaho, but with MySQL.  They don't really know anything about PostgreSQL.  There are some important difference between PostgreSQL and MySQL.  Including the fact that PostgreSQL supports schemas (whereas MySQL uses separate database... similar in concept be behave differently in some ways).  Some ORMs (and tools) don't really like this...  for example, the [Django](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6148) framework still doesn't really fully support schemas in Postgresql (I know this because I use Python and Django often and my life is much better when I keep things in the "public" schema).  Because of my experience with Django and PostgreSQL schemas, I'm a bit leery of moving this data to a new schema.

I do understand that where ever the tables are, they will need permissions to be able to access the data.

My *explicit* questions:

- Do you use Pentaho to access a PostgreSQL database to access tables in schemas other than "public" (the default).
- If so, does it just work (no problems)?
- If you had problems, would you please be willing to share with me (and the Stackoverflow community) any online resources that helped you?  Or would you be willing to detail what you remember here?
- Do you know of anything that just won't work correctly?  For example, an open bug in Pentaho related to this topic.

Again, it's not your standard kind of question.  I'm hoping that someone out there has experience and is willing to share it here and save me from having to spend time setting up a new Pentaho instance and trying to learn Pentaho well enough to test it, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ...  I thought I made it pretty clear.  And I quote: "before I do this, I would like to see if anyone knows of a reason this will fail or be a bad idea. (or if you've done it an it works great, please let me know that, too)."

Comment: What did you try? Did you create a new schema, copy some tables into it, and try running reports against those tables? What happened when you did that? Any error messages? Also, by *non-public*, do you mean a schema that's named something besides *public*, or do you mean a schema named something besides *public* that has restricted permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pentaho steps (table inputs, outputs, etc.) usually allow you to specify a database schema.

I did a quick test using PDI and our 8.4 Postgres instance and was able to explore, read from and write to tables in different schemas.

So, I think this is a reasonable direction.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @David S:  No prob.  I'm not very familiar with the implications of using the various Postgres JDBC drivers across versions, but the current version of the Pentaho design tools ships with 8.4 drivers.  May not be a problem or your contractors may have updated, but thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 2):

Two paths you can take:

1) What previous post said ("Pentaho steps (table inputs, outputs, etc.) usually allow you to specify a database schema.")

2) In database connection, advanced tab, "The preferred schema name".

If you're working with different schemas, you can create one database connection per schema. With this approach you can leave schema field in input/output steps empty.

Answer (score 2):

We use MS SQL server and I can tell you that Pentaho does struggle with the idea of a schema. Many of their apps allow you to select a schema but Pentaho, like you said, is built to use something like mySQL.

Make you pentaho database user work like it would be working in mySQL.

We made the database user default to dbo then we structured our tables like dbo.dimDimension,
dbo.factFactTable etc. Basically, only use dbo for Pentaho purposes. (Or whatever schema you want to default to.)

Answer (score 2):

I use PDI and PgSQL extensively every day with a bunch of different schemas. It works fine. The only trouble you might run into is Pg's troublesome practice of forcing unquoted identifiers to lower instead of upper case. I soon realized everything was easier when I set the Advanced connection property to "Quote all in database".

Yes, you have to quote everything when you type SQL if PDI doesn't do it for you, but it works quite well. Haven't experimented with forcing all identifiers to lower case, but I expect that would work as well.

And yes, use the "Preferred schema nanme" as well, but be aware that some steps use that option and others don't. You can't, for example, expect it to add schema names to SQL you type into a Table Input step.

The only other issues you might run into are the limits of Pg's JDBC driver. It's not as good as SQL Server's or DB2's, but the only thing I've every had trouble with was sending error rows from a Table Output step to another step when the Table Output step was in batch mode.

Have fun learning PDI. It makes a great complement to your DBA skills.

Brian

Comment: Thanks!  I really appreciate the response.  I got hammered for the initial question (even got a couple of down votes - lol).  I appreciate the advice.